# Connecting a menu item to a xib file cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I have this menu item that I want to connect to my xib file and was wondering how to do it?
  I thought this might be like regular Xcode but it is nothing like the way I thought it would be. Really appreciate it if you help me.

```
    CCMenuItemImage *gamecenter = [CCMenuItemImage
                                itemFromNormalImage:@"gamecenter.png"
                                selectedImage:@"gamecenter.png"
                                target:self
                                selector:@selector(gamecenter:)];

    option1.position =ccp(50,-150);

    CCMenu *menu6 = [CCMenu menuWithItems: option2, nil];
    [menuLayer addChild: menu6];        

    - (void) option2: (id) sender
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[GameCenterViewController scene]];


 }
```

I know you probably don't use GameCenterViewController (the xib file) to replace scene. But just putting it up to kind of show what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I assume GameCenterViewController is a Cocos2d CCLayer. If it's not, let me know and I'll edit the answer...

```
- (id)init
{
    CCMenuItemImage *gameCenterMenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage
                                  itemFromNormalImage:@"gamecenter.png"
                                  selectedImage:@"gamecenter.png"
                                  target:self
                                  selector:@selector(gamecenter:)];

    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: gameCenterMenuItem, nil];

    [menuLayer addChild: menu];
}

- (void)gamecenter: (CCMenuItem *)menuItem 
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[GameCenterViewController scene]];
}
```